# Excel VBA Userform IIf(IsDate) doesn't save blank

Tags: excel, vba, date, userform

Morning all, 
I've got a workbook, with a number of UserForms on which allow entry of multiple types of data, including text, numerics, and a lot of date fields. All seems to be working well, except if a user wants to delete a date, using the appropriate userform, it doesn't overwrite the value in the worksheet. Below is the code I'm using to check if the value in the userform is a date, and then populate the worksheet, but it's doing nothing. Any help appreciated.

```
ws.Cells(lastRow, txtCollectionDate.Tag).Value = IIf(IsDate(txtCollectionDate), CDate(txtCollectionDate), "")
```

Update: txtCollectionDate is a textbox, it's value originally was 09/01/2016, but the user wants to delete this, as it was entered in error. User should be able to highlight the value, press delete (keyboard), then save.

Comment: Please show the content of `txtCollectionDate` if it does nothing and mention what are your default date settings for short date in Excel and in your operating system.

Comment: Thanks Axel, updated the main question. default date settings in Excel/OS are dd/mm/yyyy (UK style)

Comment: `it doesn't overwrite the value in the worksheet` - does that mean it does _nothing_? or that it replaces the value with blank?

Comment: Hi Macro Man, it didn't do anything. I wanted it to replace the value with a blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as if with `IIf` the then part will be processed even if the criterion part is not true. This leads to an error 13 type mismatch with `CDate("")`.

So you should do:

```
If IsDate(txtCollectionDate) Then
 ws.Cells(lastRow, txtCollectionDate.Tag).Value = CDate(txtCollectionDate)
Else
 ws.Cells(lastRow, txtCollectionDate.Tag).Value = ""
End If
```

**Edit:**

Delete "Seems". That behavior is documented:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264412.aspx

Comment: Thanks Axel, this works a treat. I had considered this, but was trying to keep the code as 'clean' as possible.....this works though, so thank you. Now to apply the same logic to the other 8 dates :)